# Angular 2 extending component - how to inherit styles

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-components

I want to extend component and override its html template only, but left all logic and styles. Unfortunately I see that all styles defined in parent component was not inherited. Is there the way to use styles of the component that was extended?
P.S. This is comoponent defined in node_modules, so I can edit source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bleed styles down to a component. You would put this on your target component.

```
   @Component({
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
  })
```

Comment: It's not working. ViewEncapsulation should be in parent component isn't it? But I cannot modify parent component.

Comment: FYI this wouldn't have fixed the issue. I tried in my own node_module. Encapsulation is to do with the styles being restricted to that element within the site, we still want this to happen but have the styles inherit from the *extended* component, not *nested* component.